# Чем сделать распознавание капчи?

Tags: c#, .net, captcha, распознавание-образов, распознавание-символов

С помощью чего лучше реализовать распознавание цифр из такого изображения?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал с помощью [tessnet2](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/) и [puma.net](http://pumanet.codeplex.com), но они неверно распознают половину цифр.

Comment: а это единицы или семерки?

Comment: @Grundy единицы же, как будто прямиком с лого Первого канала)

Comment: @Denis, ну не знаю, на мой взгляд, это скорее повернутые семерки

Comment: Сложная задача и для человека, иногда, распознавание. Но алгоритмы обычно % похожести дают. @J.Doe, попробуйте лучше прогнать по кол-ву попаданий для обоих библиотек. Раз уж вы их опробовали, то можете сравнить. И для проверок используйте не только этот пример. Он не самый простой, как минимум из-за подобных "1" и "7".

Comment: Если авторы капчи непереусердствовали, то наверняка "1" и "7" промеж себя различаются заметно. При этом, глядя на "3", видно, что форма одних и тех же цифр одинакова, даже наклон один и тот же (может это сохраняется и между отдельными картинками). А если так много одинаковостей, то почему бы не собрать все цифры, да не попробовать какой-нибудь хэш или машинное обучение. Просто распознавалки текста, они как правило на стандартные шрифты рассчитаны без учёта деформаций символов и их экзотических форм, а потому и дают большую погрешность для капч.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, 3 по счету это 7. Единица просто как прямая линия. Так как лучше поступить? Эти две библиотеки вообще не справляются с задачей, они распознают только цифру 3.

Comment: Если цифры только такие (или их кол-во ограничено некоторым разумным числом и не будет значительно увеличиваться в будущем), то можно попробовать "обучить" программу понимать что за цифры перед ней. Тут тогда главная задача это научить программу отделять одну цифру от другой. А далее дело техники сравнить отдельные цифры с базой знаний в которую занесены изображения всех известных цифр и их значения...

Comment: Alexey, Здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ, скажите, а можно ваш скайп или тому подобное, очень нужно задать один вопрос?) Спасибо

Comment: @J.Doe: skype dumcheg